# Codeigniter Pagination in loaded Ajax page Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

PS. I know there are abundant answers for this but they seemed so complex and I'm just a beginner in codeigniter and jquery with semantic UI so I'm having difficulty in web development.

I want to know how you can implement pagination in my code from the page which is loaded with an ajax function. I find it very difficult combining ajax with codeigniter and im not a very skilled programmer so please help me on this.

The java script which it loads all the data

```
function viewhardware(){
   $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "gethw",
        async: true,
  }).done(function( data ) {
  $('#hardware').html(data);
  });
}
```

The Controller function

```
public function gethw(){
        $this->load->model('asset_model');
        $this->data['hwares'] = $this->asset_model->get_allhw();
        $this->load->view('gethware',$this->data); 
    }
```

My Model function

```
public function get_allhw(){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('hardware h'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        if($query->num_rows() != 0)
        {   
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
```

and the VIEW

```
    <table class="ui compact table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Date Installed</th>
      <th>Serial No.</th>
      <th>PC ID</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


  <center><i class="huge desktop icon""></i><h3>Hardwares</h3>
              <hr>
                <?php 

                   if(!empty($hwares)){
                      foreach($hwares as $hwares){
                             $hw_id = $hwares['hw_id'];
                             $hw_name = $hwares['hw_name'];
                             $hw_description = $hwares['hw_description'];
                             $hw_dateinstalled = $hwares['hw_dateinstalled'];
                             $hw_serialno = $hwares['hw_serialno'];
                             $hw_comp_id = $hwares['hw_comp_id'];
                             $hw_status = $hwares['hw_status'];
                     ?>
              <tr>
                  <th>
                   <?php echo $hw_id; ?>   
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_name; ?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_description; ?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_dateinstalled; ?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_serialno; ?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_comp_id;?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     <button class="ui basic button"> 
                     <center><i class=" <?php if($hw_status==1){ echo 'green';}else{ echo 'red'; }; ?> 
                                desktop icon"></i>
                     </button>
                  </th>


                  <th><a id="editpc" class="ui button mini yellow"><i class="write icon"></i></a>
                  <a class="ui mini red button" href="#"><i class="remove icon"></i></a></th>       


                 </tr>

                     <?php 
                        }
                        }
                      ?>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: where have you got struk??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ajax_pagination library.

[Here](http://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-in-codeigniter-framework/) you will find example of how to use it.

Your controller should looks like:

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('Ajax_pagination');
        $this->perPage = 1;
    }
public function gethw(){
        $this->load->model('asset_model');
        
        //total rows count
        $totalRec = count($this->asset_model->getRows());
        
        //pagination configuration
        $config['first_link']  = 'First';
        $config['div']         = 'div-to-refresh'; //parent div tag id
        $config['base_url']    = base_url().'controller/ajaxPaginationData';
        $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
        $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;
        
        $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
        
        //get the posts data
        $this->data['hwares'] = $this->asset_model->getRows(array('limit'=>$this->perPage));
        $this->load->view('view1',$this->data); 
    }
 function ajaxPaginationData()
    {
        $page = $this->input->post('page');
        if(!$page){
            $offset = 0;
        }else{
            $offset = $page;
        }
        
        //total rows count
        $totalRec = count($this->asset_model->getRows());
        
        //pagination configuration
        $config['first_link']  = 'First';
        $config['div']         = 'div-to-refresh'; //parent div tag id
        $config['base_url']    = base_url().'controller/ajaxPaginationData';
        $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
        $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;
        
        $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
        
        //get the posts data
       $this->data['hwares'] = $this->asset_model->getRows(array('start'=>$offset,'limit'=>$this->perPage));
        
        //load the view
        $this->load->view('view2', $this->data, false);
    }
```

You have to split your view in 2 parts
**VIEW1**

```
<div id="hardware">
<div id="div-to-refresh">
    <?php $this->load->view('view2',$this->data); ?> 
</div>
<div id="pagination"><?php echo $this->ajax_pagination->create_links(); ?></div>  
</div>
```

**view2**

```
<table class="ui compact table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Date Installed</th>
      <th>Serial No.</th>
      <th>PC ID</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


  <center><i class="huge desktop icon""></i><h3>Hardwares</h3>
              <hr>
                <?php 

                   if(!empty($hwares)){
                      foreach($hwares as $hwares){
                             $hw_id = $hwares['hw_id'];
                             $hw_name = $hwares['hw_name'];
                             $hw_description = $hwares['hw_description'];
                             $hw_dateinstalled = $hwares['hw_dateinstalled'];
                             $hw_serialno = $hwares['hw_serialno'];
                             $hw_comp_id = $hwares['hw_comp_id'];
                             $hw_status = $hwares['hw_status'];
                     ?>
              <tr>
                  <th>
                   <?php echo $hw_id; ?>   
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_name; ?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_description; ?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_dateinstalled; ?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_serialno; ?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  <?php echo $hw_comp_id;?>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     <button class="ui basic button"> 
                     <center><i class=" <?php if($hw_status==1){ echo 'green';}else{ echo 'red'; }; ?> 
                                desktop icon"></i>
                     </button>
                  </th>


                  <th><a id="editpc" class="ui button mini yellow"><i class="write icon"></i></a>
                  <a class="ui mini red button" href="#"><i class="remove icon"></i></a></th>       


                 </tr>

                     <?php 
                        }
                        }
                      ?>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

I can not write all code for you but this can help you.
**Make changes in your model to match with this.**

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: and 13 minutes latter?

Comment: i already tried that but its too complex for my level so i really need help on this.

Comment: @JayaVishwakarma it didnt work recieved an error in console Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 500 (Internal Server Error) please help

Comment: Sorry but I can only help you if I have full access to your code.